# nodejs + express where load context configuration from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, configuration

my scenario id a nodejs + express app connected to a mysql database.

There are some context configurations, valid for all the website and all users, that I need to load from the database at every page request (not at app init because I don't want to reload the entire server when the configuration changes).

My idea was to use a simple middleware to inject the context into the request, like that:

```js
const express = require('express');
const contextSetup = require('./contextSetup');

const app = express();
...
app.use(contextSetup.middleWare);
...
```

and in `contextSetup.js`:

```js
const DB = require('./DB');

module.exports.middleWare = (req, res, next) => {
  DB.query('select `code`, `data` from `setting` order by `sort`')
    .then((rows) => {
      const keyVals = {};
      rows.forEach((row) => {
        keyVals[row.code] = row.data;
      });
      req.appContext = keyVals;
      next();
    })
    .catch((err) => next(err));
};
```

The only warning is to use the middleware after `app.use(express.static());` otherwise my middleware would be called even for static files request (images, css, js, ...).

Is this approach correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this works in my book! I might suggest that you put this on a router, so this works only for logged in users, for example. You might also further isolate your routers so that if there are any ajax routes, that these values are not requeried only to be ignored. So the code seems fine, and if performance becomes an issue, just implement a cache which, say, refreshes every half minute or ten requests. But its only one query, so that seems fine for now.